# MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type with react-django heroku deploy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, heroku

I've been getting the error "MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type" on my django+react deploy on Heroku. This is mostly because django can't find the staticfiles from react.

Setting staticfiles dir in settings.py should have solved the problem, but it didn't:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static'),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided to create this question with self answer because I spend a very long and frustrating afternoon solving this issue since I didn't find the right solution anywhere on the web.

What I did wrong in my deployment was setting my buildpacks the wrong way when I set up the project for heroku. Don't be me and immediately go to StackOverflow and find the solution there.

**To serve the staticfiles correctly** obviously python and collectstatic has to run after npm build from react. Thus **add python buildpack after nodejs in Heroku**:

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs
heroku buildpacks:add --index 2 heroku/python
```

Comment: Hey Phil, I have a similar problem in production and localhost will you please check my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73437331/mime-type-text-html-is-not-a-supported-stylesheet-mime-type-and-strict-mime