# MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled - DJANGO + REACTJS App

Tags: reactjs, django, digital-ocean, mime-types, django-staticfiles

I have a django + reactjs application that I have deployed in **digitalocean app platform**. I am using the production build, made with command `npm rub build`, of reactjs and serving it with the django. I am using digitalocean spaces for static and media files sotrage and serving.

Now after deployment I am getting the following errors in the console:

```
Refused to apply style from 'https://solvelitigation.com/static/css/main.e8b3c255.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Refused to apply style from 'https://solvelitigation.com/static/css/main.e8b3c255.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

efused to execute script from 'https://solvelitigation.com/static/js/main.a796034b.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.

Refused to apply style from 'https://solvelitigation.com/static/css/main.e8b3c255.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Because of the above errors nothing is being rendered in the page.

#### I have no idea why this is happeing and how to solve them. Please suggest to me how to solve this.

I have tried a number of solutions from SO but none seems to work for me. I am getting the same errors when I am trying to run the app from localhost too.

##### Following are my settiings

**cdn/conf.py** (where I have configured my spaces settings)

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID= os.environ.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")

AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= os.environ.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = "bucket name"

AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL="endpoint"

AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'

AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    "CacheControl":"max-age=86400",
}

AWS_LOCATION = f"location of the bucket"

STATIC_URL = f'{AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL}/static/'

MEDIA_URL =  f'{AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL}/media/'

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "solvelitigation_back.cdn.backends.MediaRootS3Boto3Storage"

STATICFILES_STORAGE = "solvelitigation_back.cdn.backends.StaticRootS3Boto3Storage"
```

**settings.py**(where the are being imported as follows)

```
from .cdn.conf import (
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME,
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL,
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL,
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS,
AWS_LOCATION,
STATIC_URL,
MEDIA_URL,
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE,
STATICFILES_STORAGE,
)


AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS
AWS_LOCATION
STATIC_URL
MEDIA_URL
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE
STATICFILES_STORAGE

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles' 

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'mediafiles'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        BASE_DIR / 'build/static',
    ]
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('account/',include('account.urls')),
    path('civil/',include('civil.urls')),
    path('criminal/',include('criminal.urls')),
    path('corporate/',include('corporate.urls')),
    path('service/',include('service.urls')),
    path('taxation/',include('taxation.urls')),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                          document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)


# This is will cath the routes in the frontend and 404 errors
urlpatterns += [re_path(r'^.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))]
```

**index.html** this the html from react

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/static/images/favicon-icon.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Install whitenoise**

`pip install whitenoise`

**Add MiddleWare**

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
]
```